# Java Login Method with Database Connection failing to complete

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx, database-connection

Searched for an answer to this but can't find anything similar. Checked the questions which may already have my answer as well but again no solution.

So first of all, here is the code which doesn't complete:

```
    Class.forName(DRIVER);

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER,
            PASS);

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    e = email.getText();
    p = password.getText();
    String SQL = "SELECT email, password FROM healthcareProfessional WHERE email = '" + e
            + "' AND password = '" + p + "';";

    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (email.getText().equals(resultSet.getString("email"))
                && password.getText().equals(resultSet.getString("password"))) {
            Main.applyHomescreenLayout();
        } else if (email.getText().equals("") || password.getText().equals("")) {
            errorMessage.setText("Incorrect Email.");
            errorMessage.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000.0), errorMessage);
            fadeTransition.setFromValue(3000.0);
            fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
            fadeTransition.playFromStart();
        }
    }
```

Everything here works fine provided I enter valid login credentials. However, if I leave the email or password blank and try to log in, no message is displayed and I can't understand why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Also, if I remove the connection the below code works perfectly and the message is displayed.

```
if (email.getText().equals("") || password.getText().equals("")) {
        errorMessage.setText("Incorrect Email or Password.");
        errorMessage.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000.0), errorMessage);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(3000.0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeTransition.playFromStart();
    }
```

I have also tried closing the resultset, statement and connection within the if and else if statements, replacing the .equals("") with .isEmpty(), and using separate resultsets, none of which worked.

Comment: is an exception being thrown?

Comment: No, no exceptions at all.

Comment: Under what conditions are you expecting to reach that `else` block?

Comment: I missed the obvious. I've got the answer now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any message when the email and password are not blank but does not match?

It seems that if there is no matching combination the resultSet will be empty and  [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) will always evaluate as false, completely skipping the while loop.

What I would do (no compiler here, so the code can have mistakes) is:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
if (resultSet.next()) {
    //No need to re-validate
    Main.applyHomescreenLayout();
} else {
    //no email|password combination found on database
    errorMessage.setText("Incorrect Email.");
        errorMessage.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000.0), errorMessage);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(3000.0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeTransition.playFromStart();
}
```

This was said before but is always good to be reinforced: take a look at prepared statements to avoid sql injections.

Comment: Great answer. I'll be able to work with this. Thanks.

Comment: I would also suggest to use a different message when you have a blank email/password just to be clear to the user about what he is doing wrong. Maybe you could re-use   the code inside the else statement and put it inside a showErrorMessage(String message) function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this check must be before checking Database, i.e. before execution of DB query to check for user credentials.

```
if (email.getText().equals("") || password.getText().equals("")) {
            errorMessage.setText("Incorrect Email.");
            errorMessage.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000.0), errorMessage);
            fadeTransition.setFromValue(3000.0);
            fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
            fadeTransition.playFromStart();
        }
```

You must not allow anyone with no password or no email id to sniff your database check.

Secondly but your DB connection in try catch block and in finally block release all connection objects,statement objects.

Thirdly use prepared statement to protect your system from sql injections.It is not good practice to create query in this way.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip about use of a Prepared Statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` block is essentially unreachable.

Your SQL statement selects only rows in the database table for which the database `email` field is equal to the text in the `email` text field, and for which the database `password` field is equal to the text in the `password` text field (or `PasswordField`, presumably).

So if the user leaves either `email` or `password` blank, it will select only rows from the database for which `email` is blank or `password` is blank, respectively. In that case, for any row in the result set, the test

```
if (email.getText().equals(resultSet.getString("email"))
    && password.getText().equals(resultSet.getString("password")))
```

will still evaluate to `true`, so you won't reach the `else` block. If there are no such rows in the database table, then you simply get an empty result set and your `while` loop iterates zero times, so you won't reach the `else` block (or even the `if` block) under those conditions either.